# ValueError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 5 columns,

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

k =  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
v = [['Dog', 'cat', '1', 'ab1'],["Dog", 'cat', '1', '00','abb1']]
Below is the error while creating a data frame. ( df = pd.DataFrame(v, columns=k) )
ValueError: 4 columns passed, passed data had 5 columns,

( df = pd.DataFrame(v, columns=k) )

I am excepting to create a data frame.

Comment: How would the desired output look like?

Answer (score 0):

The expected output is unclear, you can trim the lists to the minimal common length with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'0': dict(zip(k, v))}, orient='index')

# or
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(k, v)), orient='index').T
```

Output:

```
     A    B  C    D
0  Dog  cat  1  ab1
```

To fill the longest with None, use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest:

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'0': dict(zip_longest(k, v))}, orient='index')
```

Output:

```
     A    B  C    D     E
0  Dog  cat  1  ab1  None
```